# jQuery close window if title =

Tags: jquery, window

I am wanting to close a browser window if the page title is the same as I am requesting.

I have a CRM I built for this company and they use vicidial what I need to do is close the popup window which i have already changed the title of the page to

companyname - vicidial

I want to close that window if that title has been set

Comment: What did you try, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get title by `document.title` 
so:

```
if (document.title === "the title you want") {
    window.close();
}
```